# CASE statement when criterias are in different rows and columns

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, pivot

**[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0df9ce46a8ae7a215f85f132e4399c1f)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    campaign VARCHAR(255),
    event_type VARCHAR(255),
    event_date VARCHAR(255),
    quantity VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO sales
(campaign, event_type, event_date, quantity)
VALUES 
("C001", "buy", "2019-05-08", "500"),
("C001", "sale", "2019-04-20", "400"),

("C002", "buy", "2019-06-07", "800"),
("C002", "sale", "2019-06-15", "900"),

("C003", "buy", "2020-02-23", "700"),
("C003", "sale", "2020-03-17", "300"),

("C004", "buy", "2020-04-05", "200"),
("C004", "sale", "2020-03-17", "600");
```

The table displays the `event_types (buy, sell)` and the corresponing `quantities` per `campaign`.

---

Now, I want to run a `query` which checks the following:

a) `event_date` for `event_type` `buy` > `event_date` for `event_type` `sell` 
b) `quantity` for `event_type` `buy` > `quantity` for `event_type` `sell`

The result should look like this:

```
campaign     Check_Date     Check_Quantity
C001            Error            OK
C002            OK              Error
C004            OK              Error
```

---

I think I need to go with the `CASE` statement somehow like this:

```
SELECT
campaign, 
(CASE WHEN event_date of buy > event_date of sale THEN "Error" ELSE "OK") AS Check_Date,
(CASE WHEN quantity of buy > quantity of sale THEN  "Error" ELSE "OK") AS Check_Quantity
quantity
FROM sales;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the table in 2 queries, then join and use `CASE` expressions:

```
select
  b.campaign,
  case when b.event_date > s.event_date then 'Error' else 'OK' end Check_Date,
  case when b.quantity > s.quantity then 'Error' else 'OK' end Check_Quantity
from (select * from sales where event_type = 'buy') b
inner join (select * from sales where event_type = 'sale') s
on s.campaign = b.campaign
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0a16667f892b20102a6c5fadd372dfed).
Results:

```
> campaign | Check_Date | Check_Quantity
> :------- | :--------- | :-------------
> C001     | Error      | Error         
> C002     | OK         | OK            
> C003     | OK         | Error         
> C004     | Error      | OK
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=dc9364c1569d351ff7e5174f79e04264

Answer (score 2):

You want to compare values across rows, so this suggests aggregation. You can then implement the logic with `case` expressions:

```
select
    campaign, 
    case when 
        max(case when event_type = 'buy' then event_date end) 
            > max(case when event_type = 'sale' then event_date end)
            then 'OK'
            else 'Error'
    end check_date,
    case when 
        max(case when event_type = 'buy' then quantity end) 
            > max(case when event_type = 'sale' then quantity end)
            then 'OK'
            else 'Error'
    end check_date
from sales
group by campaign;
```

In **[your DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0ded430a4b9c118aeafae4a591893fd2)**, this produces:

```
campaign | check_date | check_date
:------- | :--------- | :---------
C001     | OK         | OK        
C002     | Error      | Error     
C003     | Error      | OK        
C004     | OK         | Error
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sub-query & do aggregation :

```
select t.campaign, 
       (case when buy_dt > sale_dt then 'OK' else 'Error' end) as Check_date,
       (case when buy_qty > sale_qty then 'OK' else 'Error' end) as Check_qty
from (select s.campaign, 
             max(case when s.event_type = 'buy' then s.event_date end) as buy_dt,
             max(case when s.event_type = 'sale' then s.event_date end) as sale_dt,
             max(case when s.event_type = 'buy' then s.quantity end) as buy_qty,
             max(case when s.event_type = 'sale' then s.quantity end) as sale_qty
      from sales s
      group by s.campaign 
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT t1.campaign, 
       CASE WHEN t1.event_date > t2.event_date
            THEN 'OK'
            ELSE 'Error'
            END Check_Date,
       CASE WHEN t1.quantity > t2.quantity
            THEN 'OK'
            ELSE 'Error'
            END Check_Quantity
FROM sales t1
JOIN sales t2 USING ( campaign )
WHERE t1.event_type = 'buy'
  AND t2.event_type = 'sale';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2b70abaf630a411f404191b31c3e6ad9)

For the result to be meaningful you MUST add unique index by `(campaign, event_type)` and restrict values list safe for `event_type` field (make it ENUM?).

Also you have not specified what must be returned for a campaign when only one record for it exists - my query will not return such campaign at all.